# Passing multidimensional arrays to functions?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function setPosition declared like:

```
void setPosition(char ***grid, int a, int b) {
    int x = a / 8;
    int xbit = a % 8;
    int y = b;
    (*grid)[x][y] |= 1 << xbit;
}
```

and in my main, I have:

```
char grid[1000][1000];
setPosition(&grid, 10, 5);
```

But I get "warning: passing argument 1 of ‘setPosition’ from incompatible pointer type". why?

Comment: C or C++, which is it?  The "correct" answer will vary.  They're not the same language, AARRRGH! :D

Comment: C, my bad, I tagged C++ on accident and forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are not the same type, even though arrays do *decay to pointers* when passed to functions. You can change the method signature to take an array

```
void setPosition(char grid[][1000], Pos *p)
```

but if you are doing C++, `vector<vector<char> >` would provide a much better and more flexible option.

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to / replaced with / "decay" to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element in the array.

If you call your function as

```
setPosition(grid, 10, 5);
```

the expression `grid` will have type `char [1000][1000]`, which by the rule above will be replaced with an expression of type `char (*)[1000]`, so your function prototype would need to be

```
void setPosition(char (*grid)[1000], int a, int b) { ... }
```

or

```
void setPosition(char grid[][1000], int a, int b) { ... }
```

which in this context is the same thing.

If you call your function as

```
setPosition(&grid, 10, 5);
```

then the expression `&grid` has type `char (*)[1000][1000]`, so your function prototype would need to be

```
void setPosition(char (*grid)[1000][1000], int a, int b) { ... }
```

and you would need to explicitly dereference `grid` before applying any subscript, as in

```
(*grid)[a][b] = ...;
```